# JAVA Gson Flex Empty ARRAY

Tags: java, arrays, json, apache-flex, gson

the problem is as so:

I have a java server running on tomcat 7.0 and having the library Gson 2.1 on it.
I have and object to be encoded into json that got an attribute which is an array and might be an empty one.

when I send my json object via the response writer to the Flex Builder 4.5 in the Network Monitor view in the response type I get unknown.

well, I have done my research, and discover  that this is a known issue.

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2696445

adobe said that with Flex Builder 4.5 this issue will be fixed. but apparently it ain't so.

this is the server code :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Manifest man = new Manifest();
    man.setDeposits(action.viewClientDeposits(client));
    String json = new Gson().toJson(man);
    response.getWriter().print(json);
}

class Manifest {
private List<DepositDTO> deposits;
public List<DepositDTO> getDeposits() {
    return deposits;
}
public void setDeposits(List<DepositDTO> deposits) {
    this.deposits = deposits;
}
```

can someone please explain how to workaround it?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **serializers.swc** attached to this ticket:
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-26409

It should work for you.
Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for replying!
what should i do with the serializers.swc file?
just add it to the buildpath??

Comment: You can replace the existing one here (Windows 7 x64 path, adapt your own): C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\eclipse\plugins\com.adobe.flexbuilder.project_4.6.0.328916\dcradSwcs\4.5\libs